# how to manually add csrf token

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am new to lumen, I want to use csrftoken. But i don't know how can i do it manually, as i am not using the default lumen way.

I have tried many ways to implement it but i can't do it.

How can i do this.

Pls don't downvote.. i am trying it inside my blade and i am new to laravel

Comment: Can you show what you have tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have the below line inside your form

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

I recommend you to read [this](http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/routing#csrf-protection).

Comment: can i use it inside regular <form > tag ?

Comment: Ofcourse you can, So only you wanted to add it manually, If you use laravel's way then laravel will do it for you